# VBA HTML Pull Listing Info within Links

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a list of roughly 150 URL's (all to Swappa.com/xxxxxx) that I'd like to pull info from.  I have figured out how to pull the first listing from each, but am looking to expand this to pull all listings for each URL and load them into one table (on top of each other).

Sample below:

URL Example: https://swappa.com/mobile/buy/apple-iphone-6s/sprint
or 
https://swappa.com/mobile/buy/samsung-galaxy-s6/t-mobile

Desired Data:
[image]

```
Public Sub ListingInfo()
Dim cell As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
        Dim Document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", cell.Value, False
            .send
            Set Document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            Document.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Document.querySelector(".text-nowrap").innerText
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 
Document.querySelector("condition_label").innerText
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 
Document.querySelector("price").innerText
        cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = 
Document.querySelector("storage_label").innerText
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = 
Document.querySelector("color_label").innerText
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: From what I can see, seems like you are missing a few `.` in your query selectors. Namely, `"condition_label"` should be `".condition_label"`, `"price"` should be `".price"`, `"storage_label"` should be `".storage_label"`, `"color_label"` should be `".color_label"`.

Comment: You’re right - I left a few out as I was just trying to get the logic down first before expanding it to more variables.. This code works, but it only returns the info from the first listing rather than all of the listings in that page

Comment: Headline is referring to the Subtitle displaying a snippet of a description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site uses CloudFlare to protect against DDoS/DoS. This means you will almost certainly end up failing with xmlhttp as a re-direct will occur pretty quickly and you won't get the expected content during your URL loops.

You also need to handle pages not found and the CloudFlare re-direct delay if it occurs.

The following caters for those though you might want to add in some tests that there are actually urls in column A. I assume URLs are in column A of sheet1 and that information is written out starting from column B. I use arrays to speed things up and also error handling and a dict to cater for the fact not all information you want may be present on each page/for each listing.

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub GetResults()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, page As Long, ws As Worksheet, index As Long
    Dim results(), URLs(), ie As InternetExplorer, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 15

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    URLs = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A2").Value)
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(URLs))

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        For page = LBound(URLs) To UBound(URLs)
            If InStr(URLs(page), "http") > 0 Then
                .Navigate2 URLs(page)

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                t = Timer
                Do
                    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
                Loop While .document.querySelectorAll("#section_main").Length = 0

                If Not InStr(.document.body.innerHTML, "404 - Sorry, we couldn't find what you were looking for. ") > 0 And _
                   Not InStr(.document.body.innerHTML, "No listings currently for sale") > 0 Then
                    index = index + 1
                    results(index) = GetInfo(.document, URLs(page))
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(results) - 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
    End With

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rowCounter As Long, arr()

    rowCounter = 1
    Dim headers()
    headers = Array("URL", "Seller", "Feedback", "Condition", "Color", "Storage", "Price", "Headline")
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
        arr = results(i)
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
            ws.Cells(rowCounter, 2).Resize(1, UBound(arr(j)) + 1) = arr(j)
        Next
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetInfo(ByVal html As HTMLDocument, ByVal url As String) As Variant
    Dim dict As Object, results(), nodeList, numSellers As Long, counter As Long
    Dim listings As Object, listing As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "URL", url
    dict.Add "Seller", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Feedback", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Condition", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Color", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Storage", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Price", vbNullString
    dict.Add "Headline", vbNullString

    Set listings = html.getElementById("section_main").getElementsByClassName("listing_row listing_None listing_None")
    ReDim results(1 To listings.Length)

    For Each listing In listings
        counter = counter + 1
        On Error Resume Next
        dict("Seller") = listing.querySelector(".text-nowrap").innerText
        dict("Feedback") = listing.querySelector("[data-value]").getAttribute("data-value")
        dict("Condition") = listing.querySelector(".condition_label").innerText
        dict("Color") = listing.querySelector(".color_label").innerText
        dict("Storage") = listing.querySelector(".storage_label").innerText
        dict("Price") = listing.querySelector(".price").innerText
        dict("Headline") = listing.querySelector(".headline.hidden-xs.text-nowrap").innerText
        On Error GoTo 0
        results(counter) = dict.Items
        Set dict = ClearDict(dict)
    Next
    GetInfo = results
End Function

Public Function ClearDict(ByRef dict As Object) As Object
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict
        If key <> "URL" Then dict(key) = vbNullString
    Next
    Set ClearDict = dict
End Function
```

---

**References:**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m not home to test it but it looks great... Just curious though - since I was able to pull small amounts of the data with my original code, why did it need to be revised so heavily? I understood what I had, but this sub is way over my head (at the moment).

Comment: You may be fine but I noticed that at random points cloudflare would cause a re-direction and this would cause xmlhttp to fail. I think this is likely to occur in all cases of looping with xmlhttp (though whether there is a trigger point I don’t think so). It is also possibly my ip but I think that much less likely.

Comment: I originally wrote an xmlhttp version but with repeated tests it ended up failing.

Comment: One small issue - I have found that some of the listed webpages actually have no listings (for now).  When the above code hits these, it stops at this point and doesn't move on... Is there a way to adjust it so that it will continue to the next?

Comment: Can you provide me with one of those links please? Should be an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

The following script should fetch you the content you wanted to grab from the first url.

```
Public Sub GetListingInfo()
    Const Url$ = "https://swappa.com/mobile/buy/apple-iphone-6s/sprint"
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement, I&

    With HTTP
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In HTML.getElementsByClassName("listing_row")
        I = I + 1: Cells(I, 1) = post.querySelector(".text-nowrap span").innerText
        Cells(I, 2) = post.querySelector(".condition_label").innerText
        Cells(I, 3) = post.querySelector(".price").innerText
        Cells(I, 4) = post.querySelector(".storage_label").innerText
        Cells(I, 5) = post.querySelector(".color_label").innerText
    Next post
End Sub
```

Reference to add:

```
Microsoft xml, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```